# Question #0 doesn't exist, close as duplicate bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I went to close a question as a dupe, was the first one to do so, pasted the link into the duplicate dialog and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  The first picture is before, the second is after.  I've duped it multiple times now.

[image]

[image]

I've found that to get it to work I have to hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, but it'd be nice if the more intuitive <kbd>Enter</kbd> worked.

Comment: Did the small preview of the question ever appear?

Comment: @Pop, it blinked in and then the close dialog closed and the error appeared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed - small issue with allowing enter to submit the form in that input.